# Add tooltip in highchart custom button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a custom button in highChart which is displays an icon image. Below is my code for the same

```
 customButton: {
  x: -60,
  symbolSize: 15,
  width: 25,
  symbolX: 20,
  symbolY: 20,
  titleKey: "key",
  enabled: true,
  symbol: 'url(' + infoIcon + ')'
}
```

Now, i want to display a text message on hover of this button. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own tooltip and customize it via using CSS. Also setting **stickyTracking** to false and **tooltip.snap** to some value could be a good idea to avoid displaying both tooltips.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lka4w9be/

```
function(chart) {

    var button,
        tooltip;

    tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    button = chart.renderer.button('click', 100, 50).add();

    button.on('mouseover', function() {
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    });

    button.on('mouseout', function() {
        tooltip.style.display = 'none'
    });
}
```

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.snap

Comment: Is there a way to add in tool-tip of custom button? I want to do like this only

Comment: I am not sure if I understood - you want to have only the tooltip for the custom button?